# How to get the filename from file system and create a download link?

Tags: php, uploads, attachments

I have a custom page template. This template have a custom form, the user can upload a file in that form and input his/her personal infos. The file will save in the file system.

I want to create a download link for each file and display it to a table row with the other values from MYSQL. I already have a PHP snippet that will display the personal infos from MYSQL to a table rows.

Now I want to display the download link to the file that the user uploaded with their personal infos.

And how to rename the filename of the upload file? E.g. lastname_firstname.docx

Can you help me with this? My snippet for creating a link is not working.

Here's the function:

To upload a file:

```
function upload_user_file($file = array()){
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
      $file_return = wp_handle_upload($file, array('test_form' => false));
      if(isset($file_return['error']) || isset($file_return['upload_error_handler'])){
          return false;
      } else {
          $filename = $file_return['file'];
          $attachment = array(
              'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
              'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
              'post_content' => '',
              'post_status' => 'inherit',
              'guid' => $file_return['url']
          );

          $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file_return['url']);

          require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
          $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $filename);
          wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $attachment_data);

          if(0 < intval($attachment_id)){
            return $attachment_id;
          }
      }
      return false;
}
```

To create a link (Not working):

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //returns the current URL
$parts = explode('/',$url);
$dir = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts) - 1; $i++){
        $dir .= $parts[$i] . "/";
    }

echo '<td id="message"><a href="' . $dir  . $file . '">Download</a></td>';
```

Form:

```
<?php
$locations="";
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');

$locations = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT location FROM tablename ORDER BY location ASC', OBJECT);
?>

<div class="resume-form">
    <div class="rForm"></div>
        <div class="rForm">
            <h1 class="title" style="color: #d31716;">Apply Now!</h1>
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="ResumedataBank" id="ResumedataBank">
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_title" value="Resume"/>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <input type="text" name="lastName" value="" size="40" id="lastName" required/>
                        <label for="lastName">Last Name *</label>
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <input type="text" name="firstName" value="" size="40" id="firstName" required/>
                        <label for="firstName">First Name *</label>
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <input type="text" name="middleName" value="" size="40" id="middleName" required/>
                        <label for="middleName">Middle Name *</label>
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" size="40" required/>
                        <label for="Email">E-mail Address *</label>
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <input type="text" name="mobile" value="" minlength="11" maxlength="" onkeydown="sanitizeNumber()" id="mobile" required/>
                        <label for="mobile">Contact Number *</label>
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <label for="resumeFile" style="margin: 0 0 3em; position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; color: #757575; font-size: 1.25em; font-weight: 300; line-height: 50px;">Upload</label>
                        <input type="file" name="resumeFile" value="" size="40" id="resumeFile" accept=".doc,.docx,.docx"/>
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <label for="Message" style="margin: 0 0 3em; position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; color: #757575; font-size: 1.25em; font-weight: 300; line-height: 50px;">Message</label>
                        <textarea name="message" size="40" id="message" rows="4"></textarea>
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                    </div>
            <div class="resume-form-button">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="buttonv2" value="Submit">
            </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
ob_start();

$firstName = "";
$middleName = "";
$lastName = "";
$email = "";
$mobile = "";
$resume = "";
$location ="";
$position = "";
$message = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $firstName = isset($_POST['firstName']) ? $_POST['firstName'] : '';
    $middleName = isset($_POST['middleName']) ? $_POST['middleName'] : '';
    $lastName = isset($_POST['lastName']) ? $_POST['lastName'] : '';
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $mobile= isset($_POST['mobile']) ? $_POST['mobile'] : '';
    $message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : '';
        if( ! empty($_FILES)){
            $file=$_FILES['resumeFile'];
            $attachment_id = upload_user_file( $file );

        }

$sql=$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO tablename(submit_time,last_name,first_name,middle_name,mobile_number,email,message) VALUES (now(),'$lastName','$firstName','$middleName','$mobile','$email','$message')");
exit();
}
```

Comment: How do you know, which file is uploaded by which user, is there any relationship between filename and user

Comment: I want to rename the filename with this format lastname_firstname, so the file and the user can connect

Comment: logged in user can upload files or any user?

Comment: any user of the website (visitor website)

Comment: best choice for you to save file name with other details in MySQL DB, You can save attachment ID as well.

Comment: I dont want to save the file in mysql because it will cause slowdown of the site if the uploaded files will store there. let's say the total upload file is 2gb. that's why i save the file in the file system

Comment: I am not saying to save files in DB, just file name or attachment ID, this way it will be easy and fast for you to create download link.

Comment: how to do that? can you please help me

Comment: You need o share your form code.

Comment: please see the updated question

Comment: Thanks, what are you storing in the message field, seems attachment ID?

Comment: no, just a simple sentence that user want to say

Comment: Oh sorry, i missed that. You can create one more field in your table and save the attachment ID. you can get the file path using attachment ID

Comment: how? can you give me a working example

Comment: if( ! empty($_FILES)){
            $file=$_FILES['resumeFile'];
            $attachment_id = upload_user_file( $file );

        }

Comment: i hope you know how to create table field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39991/discussion-between-deepti-chipdey-and-user014019).

Comment: that's already in my code. but how to save the attachment id in the mysql?

Answer (score 1):

as per chat discussion, once you get the attachment ID you can get the url using

```
 wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_resume_id)
```

so in your case you have to

```
 wp_get_attachment_url($record_s->attachment_resume_id)
```